# Drop entire nav bar down when mouse hovers it?

Tags: html, css, json

I have a website so far and I'm not sure how to have the entire navigation bar menu dropdown. In the demonstration, this is before the hover:

[image: Before Hover]

And after the hover:

[image: After hover]

I've been looking over the web on how to do this to my own Shopify website code. Does anyone have any tips or resources for what this type of drop-down menu is called?

Answer (score 1):

You want to drop full nav to down (its called fullscreen navigation downward). Here, is the example from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use my Component Library for the **navigation drop-down.**
[Rebalance UI](https://rebalance-ui.netlify.app/components/navigation.html)

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .navbar a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font: inherit;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar a:hover,
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content .header {
        background: red;
        /* padding: 16px; */
        color: white;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }



    /* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .column {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <div class="header">
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/193/200/300.jpg?hmac=b5ZG1TfdndbrnQ8UJbIu-ykB2PRWv0QpHwehH0pqMgE" alt="" width="100" height="100">
                    </a>
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/122/200/300.jpg?hmac=OfQ8cObBgD7BOhMjqNrjqHDjO-rXiNQ4KvSd8QRAuIA" alt="" width="100" height="100">
                    </a>
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/834/200/300.jpg?hmac=9hu4aro5r8PEFwzVlhizygx4urxyeGGjgyMRXUgKOsE" alt="" width="100" height="100">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want open dropdown with animation, use below code:

```
#dropdown{
   transition:1s;
}
```

This code will do the tasks you defined in 1 second

Comment: Ah yes this would be useful. Thanks :)